# Developing a Database simplified manager, should i use JSF or JSF+Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I've been away from web java for some time and now I have to develop a simplified database manager, basically a web interface for select, update, delete and create controllers for existing tables without having to use SQL directly.

My question is, JSF with SQL queries would be enough ? I was thinking about using JSF + Hibernate but since i won't be using these entities for anything other than a simple display of information, i thought it might be like using a bazooka against an ant.

What would you guys suggest ?

Thanks in advance

PS: If this isn't the kind of question to be made here on SO, let me know and i will take it down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally don't think it'll be 'bazooka vs ant' situation.
SQL will certainly be enough for what you need, but I would prefer Hibernate (or other JPA implementation) for all the features it comes with, but also for commodity :)

I would also go with such a solution because it's a very good practice for a more complex application which could show up in the future; it's always good to be familiar with JPA.

Comment: It depends. There are situations were JPA is not the proper solution, like interacting with the database only through stored procedures.

Comment: You are right, it can turn into a real mess in the situation you described. If I were in our friends position I would still go with JPA if I could avoid stored procedures.

Comment: Ok guys :D That shed some light into my situation :) Thanks